# There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree without using FAB

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to navigate to a route and this exception happen. Have look at my code and I don't think I have a FAB and `Hero` inside this route. Is it because when you tap on each List item, it will show a dialog with Gridview on it? Someone care to explain to me how can this exception happened? It doesn't produce any error on user thought, just throw an exception.

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Daftar Dokter")),
            body: ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Divider(color: Colors.grey[400]),
              itemCount: widget.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Doctor doctor = widget.data[index];
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    _buildDialog(context, scheduleService, doctor.doctorId);
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 50,
                          height: 50,
                          child: Placeholder(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                          child: SizedBox(
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(doctor.name),
                              subtitle: Text(doctor.specializationName),
                            ),
                          )
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: According to the doc, you can't have the same tag for multiple widget.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh So we need to wrap `InkWell` with `Hero`? because we can give tag name without using `Hero`

Comment: Tested on `InkWell`? The thing is here, you need to provide each listItem with different `tag` and also receive the same tag (constructor can handle that).

Comment: Yeah, I tried to wrap the entire child (from `Inkwell`) with `Hero` and give it a tag `item$index` so each item has different tag value, but it still throw the exception.

Comment: check my answer, hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will solve your issue:

**onItem Builder:**

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Hero(
            tag: "itemTag $index",
            child: Material(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  // _buildDialog(context, scheduleService, doctor.doctorId);
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Wisgets(
                            tag: "itemTag $index",
                          )));
                },
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Item $index"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
```

**Child Widget for row**

```
class Wisgets extends StatelessWidget {
  final String tag;

  const Wisgets({Key? key, required this.tag}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      tag: tag,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Child"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text("got $tag"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, already tried your code, but still give the exception.

Comment: Have you implemented other side hero widget? I would say  check every hero tag in your project. But 1st remove this list, and see if it faces any issue without this listView. If not, replace tagName `itemTag $index` with something like `item of listView $itemTag`, for unique purpose.

Comment: Oh I see, looks like the problem is the parent route. I put some Gridview on it and it produce the exception. Thank you for your insight.